# Как ограничить количество символов в данном регулярном выражении?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть у меня такое регулярное выражение для проверки email.

```
/^[\S-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+([\w-]{2,5})$/
```

Но проблема в том, что необходимо ограничить количество символов до 60. И сделать это желательно через регулярку.

Да и хотелось бы узнать, как ограничивать количество вводимых символов в подобной регулярке.

Comment: да, прошу прощения, тут так не работает почему-то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте блок предварительного просмотра сразу после проверки начала строки:

```js
/^(?=.{1,60}$)\S+@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,5}$/
```

См. [пример использования регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/jwIOFd/1).

Заметьте, что `[\S-\.]` - это то же, что и `\S`. **Подробности**:

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?=.{1,60}$)` - позитивный блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который требует наличия от одного до 60 символов, отличных от символов перевода строки, до конца строки
- `\S+` - один и более непробельных символов
- `@` - символ `@`
- `(?:[\w-]+\.)+` - один и более повторов одного и более букво-цифровых символов, символов нижнего подчёркивания или дефисов и символа точки
- `[\w-]{2,5}` - 2-5 букво-цифровых символов, символов нижнего подчёркивания или дефисов
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: более того - `[\S-\.]` regex101 выдает ошибку про неверный диапазон `You can not create a range with a shorthand escape sequences` . не успел написать :)

Comment: @splash58 Это в PCRE выдаёт ошибку. В ECMAScript без флага `u` это [валидный шаблон](https://regex101.com/r/XXlt2Q/1). И [в .NET тоже](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5cS-%5c.%5d%2b&i=abc%40dot.com).

Comment: понятно, в этом случае он как три символа, а не как диапазон их берет

Answer (score 2):

добавьте в начало выражения

```
(?=^.{1,60}$)
```

чтобы проверить, что в строке от 1 до 60 символов